# Function must return a value, what am I missing?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm working with an Express API using Typescript

I have this method where I'm receiving some data on a callback function

```
public async getAll(): Promise<GeneralResponse> {
        locationsRepo.findAll((error: Error, locations: Location[]) => {
            let response: GeneralResponse = {
                locations: [],
                error: undefined,
            };

            if (error) response.error = error;

            response.locations = locations;

            return response;
        });
    }
```

My response is a custom object where I store an error (if exists) and an array of a custom object

As you can see in the code above I'm returning the response inside my callback function but I'm getting this error

```
A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
```

I tried to return my response outside the callback function but the returned value is empty

```
public async getAll(): Promise<GeneralResponse> {
        let response: GeneralResponse = {
            locations: [],
            error: undefined,
        };

        locationsRepo.findAll((error: Error, locations: Location[]) => {

            if (error) response.error = error;

            response.locations = locations;
        });

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like `locationsRepo.findAll` returns a value. You're just throwing it away. Your function returns nothing. (The value that you think you are returning is returned in a callback passed to `findAll`, not in your top-level function)

Comment: Use promises instead of callbacks

Comment: @Konrad you were right, I have changed my callbacks for Promises and the magic happend, thank you very much, your comment was super helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered the answer in the comments, so I'm publishing the fix I have made to my code

This is the new code on the method I shared in my question

```
public async getAll(): Promise<GeneralResponse> {
    let response: GeneralResponse = {
        locations: [],
        error: undefined,
    };

    try {
        let result: Location[] = await locationsRepo.findAll();

        if (result) response.locations = result;
    } catch (error: any) {
        response.error = error;
    }

    return response;
}
```

But I had to make changes to the other method that was returning data to the main method, I made this changes to use promises instead of callback functions

```
db.query(queryString, (error, result) => {
  if (error) return reject(error);
  return resolve(result);
})
```

Thanks to the people that commented in my question